# Prove $\frac{\mathbb Z[X,Y]}{(5,X^{2}-Y,XY+X+1)}$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-isomorphism

> Prove $\frac{\mathbb Z[X,Y]}{(5,X^{2}-Y,XY+X+1)}$ is a field.

I thought to prove that this is isomorphic with $\mathbb{\mathbb Z_{5}(X)}$, and because $5$ is prime it will follow that it's a field.

I wanted to use the first isomorphic theorem.
I wanted to use the map $\phi: Z[X,Y]\mapsto\mathbb{Z}_{5}(X)$, $f(x,y)\mapsto f(x,x^{2})$.
Now I'm proving that 1) $\phi$ is a morphism 2) $\phi$ is surjective 3)$\ker\phi=(y-x^{2},x^{3}+x+1,5)$

1. take $x,y \in \mathbb{Z[X,Y]}$ random then:

- $\phi(x+y)$=$\phi(\sum((a_{i1}a_{i2}+b_{i1}b_{i2})X^{i1}Y^{i2})$=$(\sum((a_{i1}a_{i2}+b_{i1}b_{i2})X^{i1}Y^{i2})$=$\sum((a_{i1}a_{i2}X^{i1}Y^{i2})+\sum(b_{i1}b_{i2})X^{i1}Y^{i2})$=$\phi(x)$+$\phi(y)$
- $\phi(xy)$=$\phi(\sum((a_{i1}a_{i2}b_{i1}b_{i2})X^{i1}Y^{i2})$=$(\sum((a_{i1}a_{i2}b_{i1}b_{i2})X^{i1}Y^{i2})$=$\sum((a_{i1}a_{i2}X^{i1}Y^{i2})\sum(b_{i1}b_{i2})X^{i1}Y^{i2})$=$\phi(x)$$\phi(y)$

2. i don't know how to prove this

3. let's prove two inlcusions.

- first let $f\in ker\phi$ then $f\in (Z[X,Y])([Z])$. We use the division algorithm, then there exist an $q(x,y)$ and a $r(x,y)$ so that $f(x,y)$=$q(x,y)(x^{3}+x+1)$+$r(y-x^{2})$+$5$
  met $deg(x)<deg(x^{3}+x+1)=3$

I'm not sure how to prove those things but this is what i already have. Can someone help me further.

EDIT: my answer that i tried to prove is wrong. Some of you write a solution down. But i still need to prove that it's isomorphic with your solution and i'm still struggeling with the same question how to do that exactly

EDIT:
So the people who answered my question (thank you for that) don't really see my problem now.
Well now after you guys helpt me I want to prove that
$\frac{Z[X,Y]}{5,X^{2}-Y,XY+X+1}$ is isomorphic with $\frac{F_{5}[X]}{(X^{3}+X+1)}$.
So I need to prove that for the map the map $\phi$:$Z[X,Y]$ $\mapsto$$\frac{F_{5}(X)}{X^{3}+X+1}$:$f(x,y)$$\mapsto$$f(x,x^{2})$.
Now I'm proving that 1) $\phi$ is a morphisme 2) $\phi$ is surjective 3)ker$\phi$=$(y-x^{2},x^{3}+x+1,5)$
I'm stuck with proving these three things correctly

Answer (score 8):

*Hint:*
$$
\frac{\mathbb Z[X,Y]}{\langle 5,X^{2}-Y,XY+X+1 \rangle}
\cong
\frac{\mathbb Z[X,X^2]}{\langle 5,0,X^3+X+1 \rangle}
\cong
\frac{\mathbb Z[X]}{\langle 5,X^3+X+1 \rangle}
\cong
\frac{\mathbb F_5[X]}{\langle X^3+X+1 \rangle}
$$
so it reduces to proving that $X^3+X+1$ is irreducible mod $5$, which is easy since the degree is $3$.

Comment: Moreover $X^3+X+1$ is a polynomial of degree 3 which has no roots mod 5, thus it is irreducible.

Comment: okay but I still need to prove that it's isomorphic with the last one

Comment: Just curious, for questions like this type, so $\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]$ over some set of generators, are you always able to make the 'substitution' using $Y=X^2$?

Comment: @JustWandering, yes, quotients introduce relations

Comment: Can you maybe also help or give the proof that it's isomorfic with the last one? That's were i'm stuck.  So you only told me that i'm proving the wrong stuff but could you also help with how i should prove it then?

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers tell you,

$$\frac{\mathbb Z[X,Y]}{\langle 5,X^2-Y,XY+X+1 \rangle}\cong\frac{\mathbb Z[X]}{\langle 5,X^3+X+1 \rangle}\cong\frac{\mathbb Z_5[X]}{\langle X^3+X+1 \rangle}.$$

One way to prove this is to write explicit isomorphisms. I will not do this, since even though it works, it hides how one would come up with this chain of isomorphisms.

What you need is two theorems:

> 1. (Third Isomorphism Theorem) If $I,J$ are ideals of $R$ and $I\subseteq J\subseteq R$, then $\frac RJ \cong \frac{R/I}{J/I}$.
> 2. Let $\varphi: R\to S$ be a ring isomorphism and $I$ ideal of $R$. Then $R/I \cong S/\varphi(I)$.

So, in the first isomorphism in the chain, first use the Third Isomorphism Theorem to get
$$ \frac{\mathbb Z[X,Y]}{\langle 5,X^2-Y,XY+X+1 \rangle} \cong
\frac{\mathbb Z[X,Y]/ \langle X^2 - Y \rangle}{\langle 5,X^2-Y,XY+X+1 \rangle / \langle X^2 - Y \rangle}.$$

Now we want isomorphism $\varphi\colon \frac{\mathbb Z[X,Y]}{\langle X^2 - Y \rangle}\to \mathbb Z[X]$. Since we want $X^2-Y$ to be sent to $0$, first look at the evaluation map
\begin{align}
\mathbb Z[X,Y] &\to \mathbb Z[X],\\
X &\mapsto X, \\
Y &\mapsto X^2,
\end{align}
which you can verify is surjective and has kernel $\langle X^2 - Y \rangle$. That defines $\varphi$ by the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Finally, we need to calculate $\varphi(\langle 5,X^2-Y,XY+X+1 \rangle / \langle X^2 - Y \rangle)$. Notice that
\begin{align}
5 + \langle X^2 - Y \rangle &\mapsto 5,\\
X^2 - Y + \langle X^2 - Y \rangle &\mapsto 0,\\
XY+X+1+\langle X^2 - Y \rangle &\mapsto X^3+X+1.
\end{align}

Therefore, $\varphi(\langle 5,X^2-Y,XY+X+1 \rangle / \langle X^2 - Y \rangle) = \langle 5, X^3 + X + 1\rangle$  and

$$\frac{\mathbb Z[X,Y]/ \langle X^2 - Y \rangle}{\langle 5,X^2-Y,XY+X+1 \rangle / \langle X^2 - Y \rangle}\cong \frac{\mathbb Z[X]}{\langle 5, X^3 + X + 1\rangle}.$$

I will leave the second isomorphism in the chain to you.

Comment: Very clear explanation! Hats off to you!!!

Comment: thank you i will do the same for the other chain and put it in my question

Comment: The second theorem u use, has it a name or something? I didn't saw that theorem i think so i can't use it until i prove it

Comment: and i'm really sorry but i don't see where you use the teorems at all

Comment: @mathmath, I'm not sure that it has a special name. It can easily be proven either from the First Isomorphism Theorem, or can be thought of as a consequence of a Five Lemma. If you can't use it, I would first prove it on my own, and just replicate the proof with the concrete rings and ideals each time I need it. The last isomorphism that I wrote is due to 2. (it's an easy pattern matching, take a look at my sentence "Now we want isomorphism $\varphi$..." to find $R$ and $S$ from 2.)

Answer (score 0):

If $Y=X^{2}$, then $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X,Y]}{5,X^{2}-Y,XY+X+1}=\frac{\mathbb{F}_{5}[X]}{X^{3}+X+1}$. It should be easy to see that $X^{3}+X+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{5}$.

Comment: alright but I still need to prove the equalitiy.

Comment: Just substitute $Y=X^{2}$ in $XY+X+1=0$.

Comment: Yes I did that above to prove a wrong thing. But I'm still stuck with proving that the new $\phi$ is transitive and what the kern is

Comment: I don't understand your problem.

Comment: It is easy to see that $X^{3}+X+$ is irriducibel. But first I need to prove that $Z[X,Y]/(5,X^{2}-Y,XY+X+1)$ is isomorf with your solution. I'm stuck with the proof.